# Написание обработчика списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список 1, в котором находятся названия групп и список 2, в котором расположены пары для этих групп. Сложность заключается в том, что одна пара находится в одном элементе списка. И нет четкого разграничителя –- где заканчиваются пары для первой группы, а где начинаются для второй (всего в списке 4 группы).

Имеется такой код, но он ничего не выводит. Думаю проблема в значении split()

```
lessons = ['ГП-1-22', 'ГП-2-22', 'АСУ-22', 'ГР-1-22']
schedule = ['I Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.', 'II Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.', 'III Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.', 'IV История (№22) Сафиюллина Г.М.', 'V Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.', 'I Астрономия (№29) Каргина О.А.', 'II Литература (№24) Мадиева Т.А.', 'III Биол.и эк. (нет) Асылгареева А.И.', 'IV История (№23) Гарифуллина А.Н.', 'I Матем (№27) Ризванова Г.Г.', 'II Физкультур (Больш. спортзал)', 'III Матем (№27) Ризванова Г.Г.', 'IV Литература (№24) Мадиева Т.А.', 'I Физкультур (Больш. спортзал)', 'II Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.', 'III Литература (№16) Яковлева А.А.', 'IV Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.']


schedule_by_group = {}


for group in lessons:
    schedule_by_group[group] = []


for lesson in schedule:
    for group in lessons:
        if lesson.startswith(group.split('-')[0]):
            schedule_by_group[group].append(lesson)


group = input("Введите название группы: ")
if group in schedule_by_group:
    print(f"Расписание уроков для группы {group}:")
    for lesson in schedule_by_group[group]:
        print(lesson)
else:
    print("Такой группы нет в списке.")
```

Comment: А можно подробно расписать, как должны логически связываться элементы из первого и второго списка? Сейчас это немного угадайка. Например:  'ГП-1-22' из первого списка трактовать как 1-я половина (часть, что?) групп № 22 или как? А в списке расписаний 'I Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.' это как трактуется? Как Химия для 1-ой половины (части?) группы №26 или это первая пара по Химии для группы 26 (всей)? Как бы доугадывать вводные задачи - такое себе

Comment: покажите ожидаемый вывод для ваших входных данных

Comment: "Думаю проблема в значении split()" проблема с алгоритмом решения вашей задачи. Список schedule разбить на четыре группы `['I Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.', ..., 'V Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.']`, `['I Астрономия (№29) Каргина О.А.', ..., 'IV История (№23) Гарифуллина А.Н.']`, `['I Матем (№27) Ризванова Г.Г.', ..., 'IV Литература (№24) Мадиева Т.А.']`, `['I Физкультур (Больш. спортзал)', ..., 'IV Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.']` которые можно связать со списком lessons

Comment: Вы что сайт парсили?

Comment: @СергейШ да, Я хочу разбить список на 4 группы, но не понимаю как. Закономерность Я здесь вижу, то что каждый новый список должен начинаться с 'I'. Да, Я паршу динамическую таблицу на сайте своего учебного заведения.

Comment: Может-ли быть так, что в какой-то группе занятия будут начинаться не с первой пары, а например со II, III, ? В Универах так бывает довольно часто?

Comment: @passant нет, в списке если нет 1 пары будет написано: 'I нет (нет) нет'

Comment: @n1tr0xs В идеале вот так:
Расписание пар для группы ГП-1-22:
I Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.
II Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.
III Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.
IV История (№22) Сафиюллина Г.М.
V Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.
Но мне нужно хотя бы разделить 2 список на 4 части, каждая из которых будет начинаться с элемента, содержащего 'I'

Comment: @Дмитрий Каждый элемент первого списка содержит название группы (ГП-1-22). Элемент второго списка содержит 'I' – номер пары, и 'Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.' – информацию о паре (название пары, номер аудитории, ФИО преподавателя. Хотелось бы узнать, как разделить 2 список на 4 части, каждая из которых будет начинаться с элемента, содержащего 'I'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так сделать:

```
groups = ['ГП-1-22', 'ГП-2-22', 'АСУ-22', 'ГР-1-22']
schedule = [
    'I Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.',
    'II Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.',
    'III Инфор-ка (№58) Уланова Е.В.',
    'IV История (№22) Сафиюллина Г.М.',
    'V Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.',

    'I Астрономия (№29) Каргина О.А.',
    'II Литература (№24) Мадиева Т.А.',
    'III Биол.и эк. (нет) Асылгареева А.И.',
    'IV История (№23) Гарифуллина А.Н.',

    'I Матем (№27) Ризванова Г.Г.',
    'II Физкультур (Больш. спортзал)',
    'III Матем (№27) Ризванова Г.Г.',
    'IV Литература (№24) Мадиева Т.А.',

    'I Физкультур (Больш. спортзал)',
    'II Химия (№26) Гончарова Н.А.',
    'III Литература (№16) Яковлева А.А.',
    'IV Биол.и эк. (№51) Файзуллина Г.Г.'
]

schedule_by_group = {group: [] for group in groups}

group_idx = -1

for s in schedule:    
    if s.split()[0] == 'I':
        group_idx += 1
    schedule_by_group[groups[group_idx]].append(s)
    
for key, val in schedule_by_group.items():
    print(f'Расписание для группы {key}')
    for p in val:
        print(f'\t{p}')
```